# Value-dependent optionality of property types

Tags: typescript

A tricky one.

Say one has a type, `A`, that is defined as an array of objects of two properties, `name` and `isOptional`:

```js
type A = ({ name: string, isOptional: boolean })[]
```

For example:

```js
const a: A = [
  { name: 'foo', isOptional: false },
  { name: 'bar', isOptional: true}
]
```

Say one wants to now create a type that is a dictionary with keys in `name` values of `a`, and any value type, for now let's say `string`.

This is achieved as follows:

```js
// One needs this workaround to get an "exactly-typed" value that extends `A`
const createA = <T extends Readonly<A>>(a: T): T => a

// Create exactly-typed value that extends `A`
const a = createA([
  { name: 'foo', isOptional: false },
  { name: 'bar', isOptional: true}
] as const)
/*
const a: readonly [{
  readonly name: "foo";
  readonly isOptional: false;
}, {
  readonly name: "bar";
  readonly isOptional: true;
}]
*/

// Create type that is a dictionary with keys in `name` values in `a`
type NameDict = { [name in (typeof a)[number]['name']]: string }
/*
type NameDict = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
*/
```

The question is: How would one change the above such that the properties in `NameDict` are optional dependant on the `isOptional` value in `a`.

For example:

```js
const b = doSomeMagic(a) // const b: { foo: string, bar?: string }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UAUBvKA7AhgWwgLigGdgAnAS3QHMAaKMwgeTGDIHssAbAgI1dY4iZ0UAL4BKANoBdAFAyAxu2JR5JQcAhxEAHgAqUCAA8N6ACaEoAJUGn2HENpgA%20J0kwFdYjwidRMcxXRlTAQVNUwNGCQJGSgoNCxcAgByADM%20ZNp6JhZ2TC4oVPzCaBFqWPiMHHwoZO5MEky6RmY2TgJSAFcIERkpPwtA4jE5GVBIKAA5aoARMnlgULQJROgKZHGIVlS-SXRO7G4IEikJZNXkqSkCYnIqURkgA)

Comment: sounds like you're trying to make a static type based off run time values ?
I think your inital types ought to be :
```type A = { name: string, isOptional: boolean }

const createA = <T extends readonly A[]>(a: T): T => a
```

Comment: does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjZP7w) fit your requirements? If yes, I could write up an answer

Comment: @TobiasS. Perfect, thanks. Just had a play about, looks good.

Comment: @TobiasS. How would one modify your solution to handle an optional value of `isOptional`? I.e. `type A = ({ name: string, isOptional?: boolean })[]`

Comment: Ah, one must add in another intersection to determine if it extends boolean, i.e. `extends boolean ? never : K['name']]`

Comment: If you don't like the intersection in the resulting type you can get rid of it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weXPgW), with a mapped type.