# Typescript conditionally making a property optional

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a type such as

```js
interface Definition {
    [key: string]: {
        optional: boolean;
    }
}
```

Is it now possible to construct a type `ValueType<T extends Definition>` that, for a definition

```js
{
    foo: { optional: true },
    bar: { optional: false }
}
```

outputs the type

```js
{
    foo?: string;
    bar: string;
}
```

Is that possible?

My first approach would have been a construct made of a mapped type and `Omit` which works by merging the optional and required properties into a single object. However, this requires a union type made of all the optional keys and I am at a loss on how to do that.

The basic Idea was:

```js
type ValueType<T extends Definition> = 
      { [key in keyof T]?: string } 
    & Omit<{ [key in keyof T]: string }, OptionalKeys<T>>
```

With `OptionalKeys<T>` returning the aforementioned union type made from all of the optional keys.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of what was asked yesterday?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340529/value-dependent-optionality-of-property-types#comment127801320_72340529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that behaviour with this logic:

```
type ValueType<T extends Record<string, { optional: boolean }>> = 
  (
    { [K in keyof T]?: string } &
    { [K in keyof T as T[K]["optional"] extends false ? K : never]-?: string }
  ) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
```

We create an intersection of all keys where `optional` is `true` with `?` and all keys where `optional` is `false`. The `extends infer O ? {[K in keyof O]: O[K]} : never` at the end makes the type "prettier" but is functionally irrelevant.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @jcalz. We can make it a bit shorter and also keep the order of the keys.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeBYAUFTUBmB7XAXMlLmMAJa4B2AhgDZHABOArtAL4A06WUARjSZEkJMpVoMc9AM4d07dOlCQoANXpsAKuAgAeTVAgAPYBCoATaVABKEAMa4m53QGsIIXNiibOxUhWp6Ij58OggaKih2AD5ohB4sAAoE3kwRAG0AaShySLcPL00AXQB+ImlmXIBzKKgAMhTUjOzcqHzPbygaK00sovSAIn9xegGiwxMzSyk6WSgSqGyiKggANwgmIoBaMqgKpmqoxoBKCdMLK1zsDagAeXniLJy89w7boqJbvtrltY3FNDKaAATQQag0EG0kF0MDiWCAA)

Comment: They probably don't care about key ordering, but you can encourage the compiler to walk through the keys of `T` in order when building the type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2aArW), which collapses to [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBkvxm).

Comment: that's neat !  :)

Comment: Is there also a way to make this work if the property `optional` is optional? I.e. if `optional` is `true`, then the property becomes optional and if `optional` is false, undefined or missilg alltogether then the property stays required? I have tried "inverting" the logic of the solution above by adding optionality if `optional` extends `true` but this did not work.

Comment: do you mean like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvEB4m) ?